# getting certain text into a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, character

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [finding a specific data from a text file in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892275/finding-a-specific-data-from-a-text-file-in-matlab)

I already opened the text file titled 'gos.txt'
using the following code:

```
s={}; 
fid = fopen('gos.txt'); 
tline = fgetl(fid); 
while ischar(tline) 
   s=[s;tline]; 
   tline = fgetl(fid); 
end
```

I got the result as follows:
 s =

```
'[Term]'    
'id: GO:0008150'
'name: biological_process'
'namespace: biological_process'
'alt_id: GO:0000004'
'alt_id: GO:0007582'
[1x243 char]
[1x445 char]
'subset: goslim_aspergillus'
'subset: goslim_candida'
'subset: goslim_yeast'
'subset: gosubset_prok'
'synonym: "biological process" EXACT []'
'synonym: "biological process unknown" NARROW []'
'synonym: "physiological process" EXACT []'
'xref: Wikipedia:Biological_process'
'[Term]'    
'id: GO:0016740'
'name: transferase activity'
'namespace: molecular_function'
[1x326 char]
'subset: goslim_aspergillus'
'subset: goslim_candida'
'subset: goslim_metagenomics'
'subset: goslim_pir'
'subset: goslim_plant'
'subset: gosubset_prok'
'xref: EC:2'
'xref: Reactome:REACT_25050 "Molybdenum ion transfer onto molybdopterin, Homo sapiens"'
'//is_a: GO:0003674 ! molecular_function'
'is_a: GO:0008150 ! molecular_function (added by Zaid, To be Removed Later)'
'//relationship: part_of GO:0008150 ! biological_process'
'[Term]'    
'id: GO:0016787'
'name: hydrolase activity'
'namespace: molecular_function'
[1x186 char]
'subset: goslim_aspergillus'
'subset: goslim_candida'
'subset: goslim_metagenomics'
'subset: goslim_plant'
'subset: gosubset_prok'
'xref: EC:3'
'//is_a: GO:0003674 ! molecular_function'
'is_a: GO:0016740 ! molecular_function (added by Zaid, to be removed later)'
'relationship: part_of GO:0008150 ! biological_process'
'[Term]'    
'id: GO:0006810'
'name: transport'
'namespace: biological_process'
'alt_id: GO:0015457'
'alt_id: GO:0015460'
[1x255 char]
'subset: goslim_aspergillus'
'subset: goslim_candida'
'synonym: "small molecule transport" NARROW []'
'synonym: "solute:solute exchange" NARROW []'
'synonym: "transport accessory protein activity" RELATED [GOC:mah]'
'is_a: GO:0016787 ! biological_process'
'relationship: part_of GO:0008150 ! biological_process'
.
.
.
.
```

the step after is how to take a certain charater and put it in a vector.. for example: I want to put all lines contains 'id: GO:*******' and put them in a vector, also I want to get 'is_a:  GO:*******' to a vector , note that I don't want to the characters after that in the same line .

Comment: What do you mean by *I don't want to the characters after that in the same line*? And what is a vector in this case?

Comment: ok.. as an example(refer to the above question) :I want a vector GO_terms =[GO:GO:0008150 GO:0016740.. and so (until the end of the text file)] these values are the values which comes after the word 'id:'the other vector is is_a relations=[ GO:0008150 ... until the end of the text file)], tese values are taken from the line started with is_a: GO***** . and so...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily use `regexp` here - it works for cells:

```
matching_lines = s{~cellfun('isempty', regexp(s, '^id: GO'))}

ans =

 id: GO:0008150

ans =

 id: GO:0016740
```

extracts all lines that start with `id: GO`. The `cellfun` call alone gives you a vector of 0/1, where 1 means that a string in `s` matches your query.

Similar line finds ones that contain `is_a: GO:`. Cutting unnecessary characters from the strings can also be done with `regexp`.

Extracting parts of the strings can be done using the `'tokens'` parameter of `regexp`:

```
tok = regexp(s, '^id: (GO.*)', 'tokens');
idx = ~cellfun('isempty', tok);
v   = cellfun(@(x)x{1}, {tok{idx}});
sprintf('%s ', v{:})

ans =

 GO:0008150 GO:0016740
```

Comment: first of all,,thanks for this great statement, but actually it shows only the first term id: GO:0008150

Comment: Little known fact: `cellfun` accepts string arguments. Testing one thousand evaluations of a 50-by-50 cell with `'isempty'`: 0.036047 seconds. With `@isempty`: 3.181114 seconds. With `@(x)isempty(x)`: 25.560400 seconds. Conclusion: use string arguments when doing an `isempty` on a cell :)

Comment: same problem ...what about if I want the line started with is_a but only I want the GO:********  ( with out the rest text after it)

Comment: @Gloria What do you mean? that it does not show `id_a:` terms? You can either create a second `regexp` line for that, or update this regexp, but then you will get all strings into one vector, not two separate vectors.

Comment: @Gloria `v` contains separate variables. Use `v{1}`, `v{2}`, etc

Comment: but still didn't know how to omit the rest text from the vector for the case that if I want to make a vector for GOterms for line started with : is_a relation: GO:****** .. I don't want to text after the GO term..

Comment: @gloria This is easily fixed using correct regular expression. I see that after GO there are numbers. I will give you the solution, but first try to modify `'^id: (GO.*)'` so that the term in the parentheses only accepts `GO:` and numbers. Read the help for `regexp` - it says how to identify digits. The hint: change the dot to something else.

Comment: ok.. I got it.. it is \w*  :D  thx alot

Comment: mmm.. I discover one more thing... for each Term in the text file, it should not be nesseceray to have 'is_a' or relation' line.. so can I put the value zero if there is not such line in each [Term] in the text file above??

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only want to find things at the start of a line it is quite simple:

```
found=[]
for i=1:length(s)
    temp = s{i};
    if strcmp('id: GO:',temp(1:min(7,end));
        found = [found i];
    end
end
```

Now found contains a vector with all locations of strings that start with id: GO:

I cannot try it in Matlab at the moment, but this should be about right.

Comment: Thank you for your response...but this code is not working.. the result if found=[ ].. can I put all these id: GO: terms in a one vector called, for example, GO_terms ?